# Material-Table with Select (options) fields clears field value on edit mode

Tags: reactjs, material-table

I'm using Material-Table with option fields and dropdown component like this:

```
                  {
                    title: content[lang].Basic_Service_Code,
                    field: "Basic_Service_Code",
                    editable: "always",
                    editComponent: (props) => (
                      <div style={{width:'150px'}}>
                      <Select
                        name="basicservicecode"
                        options={servicesOption}
                        value={props.value}
                        onChange={value => props.onChange(value)}
                        placeholder=""
                        onKeyDown={e => this.handleKey(e)}
                      />
                      </div>
                    ),
                  },
```

Here is servicesOption:

```
    const servicesOption = servicesFiltered.map((code) => {
      return { label: code.code, value: code.code };
    });
```

It works great on Insert (addRow), but when user **edits** a row, the value of the Select field disappears. It does not show the value. It actually clears the value because it sends "" (empty value) to the server.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not enough information, what's your `servicesFiltered` ?

Comment: Could you share an executable form of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your `Select` component is from *React-Select* library.  If so, try the following to make it work:

```js
editComponent: ({ value, onChange }) => (
        <Select
          options={fruitsList}
          name="fruitSelect"
          onChange={(selectedOption) => onChange(selectedOption.value)}
          value={value ? value.value : value}
        />
      )
```

The cause of this behaviour is related to how react-select works, the *values* are actually objects with `value` and `label` properties. Here is a sandbox with a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-table-editable-with-react-select-component-4wwd3?file=/src/App.js), try it out and let me know if that worked for you!

Full code:

```
import React, { Fragment, useState } from "react";
import MaterialTable from "material-table";
import Select from "react-select";

const originalData = [
  {
    id: "client 1",
    name: "Anna",
    fruit: "lime"
  }];

export default function CustomEditComponent(props) {
  const fruitsList = [
    { value: "lime", label: "lime-label" },
    { value: "mango", label: "mango-label" }
  ];

  const [data, setData] = useState(originalData);

  const tableColumns = [
    { title: "Client", field: "id" },
    { title: "Name", field: "name" },
    {
      title: "Choose a Fruit",
      field: "fruit",
      editComponent: ({ value, onChange }) => (
        <Select
          options={fruitsList}
          name="fruitSelect"
          onChange={(selectedOption) => onChange(selectedOption.value)}
          value={value ? value.value : value}
        />
      )
    }
  ];

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <MaterialTable
        columns={tableColumns}
        data={data}
        title="Material Table - Editable select component  "
        options={{ search: false, actionsColumnIndex: -1 }}
        editable={{
          onRowAdd: (newData) =>
            new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
              setTimeout(() => {
                setData([...data, newData]);

                resolve();
              }, 1000);
            }),
          onRowUpdate: (newData, oldData) =>
            new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
              setTimeout(() => {
                console.log("old:", oldData);
                console.log("new:", newData);
                const dataUpdate = [...data];
                const index = oldData.tableData.id;
                dataUpdate[index] = newData;
                setData([...dataUpdate]);

                resolve();
              }, 1000);
            }),
          onRowDelete: (oldData) =>
            new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
              setTimeout(() => {
                const dataDelete = [...data];
                const index = oldData.tableData.id;
                dataDelete.splice(index, 1);
                setData([...dataDelete]);

                resolve();
              }, 1000);
            })
        }}
      />
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I can now send the correct value back. Is there a way to also show the value to the user on edit mode? (instead of showing the "Select..." placeholder)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Yes, you can use `placeholder` property of the `Select` component: `placeholder="Pick a fruit" ` . I just updated the sandbox.  If my answer was helpful to you, please consider upvoting ;) .

Comment: @NicoE Just looking at your Sandbox example and it doesn't show the current value or label when in edit mode, it just shows 'Pick a fruit'.  Is this by design?
I ask because I am having problems in displaying the current label in my react-select within a react material-table